# Paypal Async Payment Adapter for OMS/SOM (Order management system)

Tags: apex, rest-api

I am trying to develop a async payment gateway adapter for PayPal in the Order Management System of salesforce.

With the flow running well, it is not working as per desired, no clue, no debug is there to get know the real issue behind it.

Is there any place I can debug the code which I write?
There can a possibility that my adapter class is not being executed at all.

Please help or suggest anything to get to know what is happening behind the scene.

I will be very thankful for this favour.

Answer (score 1):

I am having similar trouble.  I'm also writing such a payment gateway adaptor for both Paypal and Affirm.  My Paypal adaptor can run all operations but my affirm adaptor can only run capture, not refund or void.  I've had an open ticket with Salesforce for a couple months now with no response.  There are no log messages at all, the background job says "SUCCESS" but it doesn't seem to have run any of my code.  I've double, triple checked all prerequisite objects, classes, named credentials, etc.

---

UPDATE - I was thinking about this so I went back and checked my case, and lo and behold, they did answer me like a month later.  The problem was that the full amount of the order was not being captured - so when I went to refund or void, it couldn't refund or void the full amount.  Instead of giving an error it just does nothing.  They should probably fix that but in any event - check the amounts on your various authorization/capture calls and make sure they all line up dollars and cents.  In my case, I did integer division by mistake and that caused the cents to disappear.